# How can I search for a unicode character if I'm not sure it exists?

Tags: fonts, typography

I'm looking for a Unicode character that will be as similar as possible to the Avengers logo. Even without the circle. Anything that will hint at that logo for people who know it

[image: Avengers logo]

I'm not sure something like this exists, how can I go about searching for it?

Comment: https://graphemica.com/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Unicode number: 24B6
HTML-code: &#9398;
```

Ⓐ

You can easily visually search unicode characters here: http://unicode-table.com/en/

And for some *basic* shape recognition you can use [Shapecatcher.com](http://shapecatcher.com/) to draw the character you are looking for. It's not always fabulous at finding the right character (it didn't work in this case), but it can help in some instances.

Answer (score 6):

You can find a [complete list of Unicode characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters) in Wikipedia.

Here's also a list of [variations of the letter A](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix%3aVariations_of_%22a%22).